# Saving changes to an object graph in NHibernate after mapping from DTO to domain object

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, automapper, dto, change-tracking

I have the following layers in my application which I am currently designing:

MSSQL < NHibernate < Repository < WCF < Javascript

On load of its hosting web page (EditOrder.aspx?id=104), the javascript application calls the WCF service to get an Order by it's a id. The user can use the UI to modify properties of the Order and add/modify/delete child OrderLines (an order has a collection of OrderLines).

When the user presses the Save button, the javascript application posts the Order with and array of OrderLine objects as JSON to the WCF service.

The plan is to have the WCF service use AutoMapper to map between Domain Objects and DTOs. When the DTO posted by the browser is received by the WCF service, it will be mapped to the corresponding Order domain object, including its child OrderLines.

Next, it will be passed into the Repository.

Now my question: is it possible to let NHibernate take care of identifying any deleted/inserted/modified OrderLineItems when I ask it to Update my Order? If so, what is involved in getting this working?

**UPDATE: is this what the NHibernate Merge() method does?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. 
The problem you will have to circumvent is the static data that younreference in your order and orderlines. So, if your orderline is referencing some static product data, you have to build up a new orderline from the dto by assembling your domain orderline. The Dto will be your web service boundary to the outside world, usually a flatter model than your business domain model. The boundary the dto's are communicated being it an application layer or json in the browser.